# What should i do solve this error.?

Tags: sql-server

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Procedure PROC_SAVE_IMAGELIB, Line 27
>   Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_ImageLib'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ImageLib'. The duplicate key value is (112).
>   The statement has been terminated.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: **SHOW US** what you're doing to get this message! What are your table structures, what is the code being executed that results in this error?? We cannot see and read your screen - nor your mind.....

Answer (score 0):

Your Error message says that you are trying to insert a duplicate value into the Primary key column of the table dbo.ImageLib.

To avoid this Error you can Check the existence of the value before insert Like this

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.ImageLib WHERE Id = 112)
begin
 -- Your InsertQuery
end
```

Or change the Primary key as an Identity column, so it will be automatically incremented each time a new record is inserted